# set or get something under an element in xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I have the `xml` file as shown below with the below script  I can change the value of any specific element country with (root.iter). How can I modify the `neighbor` value of specific `country` for example the first or second?

```
<data>
    <country name="vers1" value="1"> (can change its value with below script)
     <neighbor name="test" value="E"/> (how to change its value?????)
    </country>
    <country name="vers2" value="2">
     <neighbor name="test" value="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="vers3" value="3">
     <neighbor name="test" value="W"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

**Code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for version in root.iter('country'):
    name=version.get('name')
    if name == "vers1":
        version.set('value', 10)
        tree.write('test.xml')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **xpath** to get target tag from the xml:

**Demo**:

```
#Change value of neighbor for  vers2 country , 
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

#tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = ET.fromstring(data)
neighbors = root.findall("country[@name='vers2']/neighbor[@name='test']")
for i in neighbors:
    i.attrib["value"] = "changed"

print "Output:", ET.tostring(root)
```

**Output**:

```
Output: <data>
    <country name="vers1" value="1"> (can change its value with below script)
     <neighbor name="test" value="E" /> (how to change its value?????)
    </country>
    <country name="vers2" value="2">
     <neighbor name="test" value="changed" />
    </country>
    <country name="vers3" value="3">
     <neighbor name="test" value="W" />
    </country>
</data>
```